# Regular Expression ^$ not working on UNIX using grep command

Tags: grep, regular-expression

I'm facing a problem in using the regular expression `^$` on UNIX.

When I type `grep '^hello$' text` on the command line, as a result it should match the "hello" word because it is the only word on a particular line in the text file. Unfortunately, it isn't doing like that.

I tried it with even when there was no word on any line except "hello" and then also it isn't working.

Comment: Is your file in DOS format with a CR at the end?  If so you need to convert to Unix format first (dos2unix).  This is common if you create files on Windows and then transfer them to Unix.

Comment: @StephenHarris How do I check that if the file is CR or not? 
I remember I created this "text" file using the `vi text` command

Comment: `file` would say something like `ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators`

Comment: @StephenHarris Can you tell me the command to find this type of file information? I can't see anything on the file if I open using the `cat text` command. Thanks

Comment: From inside `vi`, you can check using `set ff` (in command mode), and change to Unix-style endings using `set ff=unix`.

Comment: The command _is_ `file`.  eg `file mytxtfile`

Comment: Also `cat -e text` will show any CR characters as `^M`

Comment: @StephenHarris it only says "ascii text"

Comment: @steeldriver I am not been able to type this command in command mode. it is always putting me in text mode

Comment: Then you need to check for whitespace (eg spaces at the end of the line).  The command `tr ' ' ! < mytxtfile` will make them show up as `!` characters.  But you might also have TAB characters.  The `cat -e` command will show this by displaying spaces before the `$` at the end of the line.

Comment: @StephenHarris I said "hello!" I deleted that empty space using the `x` command.

Comment: That was your problem.  "hello " does not match "^hello$" because of the extra space.

Comment: You are right @StephenHarris :D Now it worked. Thanks to all experts. Much appreciated. You can put your answer I can accept it if you like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the comments, there are various reasons why this may not match, but look "invisible".

One common failure mode is the file is in DOS format.

In your case, you have hidden whitespace (space or TAB characters) at the end of the line.

Commands such as `tr ' ' ! < filename` or `cat -e filename` can help expose these characters.

Comment: By the way, `cat -e text` didn't work in my case. Only `tr ' ' ! < text` worked and displayed the empty spaces using the ! character. Why is it like that? just asking?